# How To properly loop through array in the middle of another loop?

Tags: jquery, for-loop

This is the current output

Note: 
1) the pink fenced portion repeats twice
2) The values for the pink fence, should break into new `<tr>` but now its comma separated.

[image]

This is the script that doing all the above:

```
var new_array = {};
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  new_array[i] = ({
    'catalog_name': data[i].catalog_name,
    'price': data[i].price,
    'qty': data[i].qty,
    'amt': data[i].grand
  });

  var _htlm = "<table><tr><td>"+
      "<h2 class='text-center'>POS</h2>"+
      "Merchant id: " + data[i].mem_id + 
      "<br/>Merchant Name :" + data[i].mem_name + 
      "<br/>Transaction Id :" + data[i].trans_id + 
      "</td></tr><tbody>"

  $("#print_receipt").prepend(_html);
}

var _html2 = "<table><thead><tr>"+
    "<th>Item Name</th>"+
    "<th>Unit Price</th>"+
    "<th>Qty</th><th>Amount</th>"+
    "</thead><tbody>"
$("#print_receipt tbody").append(_html2);

$.each(new_array, function() {
  var _html3 = "<table><tr><td>" + 
      this.catalog_name + "</td><td>" + 
      this.price + "</td><td>" + 
      this.qty + "</td><td>" + 
      this.amt + "</td></tr></tbody></table>";
  $("#print_receipt tbody").append(_html3);
});


for (var j = 0; j < data.length; j++) {
  var _html4 = "</tbody><tfoot><tr>"+
      "<td colspan='3'>TOTAL</td><td>" + data[j].grand + 
      "</td></tr><tr><td colspan='3'>CASH</td><td>" + data[j].cash + 
      "</td></tr><tr><td colspan='3'>CHANGE</td><td>" + data[j].change + 
      "</td></tr></tfoot></table><br/>"+
      "<table><tr><td>Customer Info<br/>Member Id: " + data[j].cust_id + 
      "<br/>Name: " + data[j].cust_name + 
      "<br/><input type='button' id='print_now' "+
      "onClick = 'window.print()' value='PRINT RECEIPT'/>"+
      "</td></tr></table>"
  $("#print_receipt").append(_html4);
}
```

Comment: Can you show us some code? Probably create a Fiddle.

Comment: sorry I added the code a bit late

Comment: @Keren for templating use templating engines like handlebars. or some other libraries.that will make your code more readable and can be easily debuggable.

Comment: @Keren I believe your html is not in properly build. Check if all tags are properly created and closed.

Comment: You can't append/prepend _incomplete tags_ / _blocks_. Those _incomplete tags_ will be either omitted or closed instantly. As of that your `$("#print_receipt").append("</tbody> ... </table> ...")` and `$("#print_receipt").prepend("<table> ... <tbody>");` will not have the result you expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT (I missunderstood the problem this was the answer):
You are creating a table, and then, after the table, a tbody. HTML creates a tbody once you create a table, so what happens is:
1- you create the table
2- inside the table, html creates a tbody
3- you open a tbody after the table. This results in having 2 tbody elements. So jquery finds both and inserts the same content in each.
Refer to line 46 in the fiddle (where you are opening the tbody, just remove the tag).

I made a fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/LgtmLtux/2/

```
var new_array = {};
var data = 
[
  {
        'catalog_name':"Tea", 
        'price':25,
        'qty':8,
        'grand':108
    },
  {
        'catalog_name':"Tea", 
        'price':25,
        'qty':8,
        'grand':108
    },
  {
        'catalog_name':"Tea", 
        'price':25,
        'qty':8,
        'grand':108
    },
  {
        'catalog_name':"Tea", 
        'price':25,
        'qty':8,
        'grand':108
    },
];
for(var i=0;i < data.length; i++)
{
    new_array[i] = 
    { 
        'catalog_name':data[i].catalog_name, 
      'price':data[i].price,
      'qty':data[i].qty,
      'amt':data[i].grand 
     };
     //Creating tables for each element in 'data'
    $("#print_receipt").prepend(
    "<table><tr><td><h2 class='text-center'>POS</h2>Merchant id: "+
    data[i].mem_id+
    "<br/>Merchant Name :"+
    data[i].mem_name+
    "<br/>Transaction Id :"+
    data[i].trans_id+
    "</td></tr><tbody>"
  ); 
}
console.log(new_array);
$("#print_receipt tbody").append( "<table><thead><tr><th>Item Name</th><th>Unit Price</th><th>Qty</th><th>Amount</th></thead><tbody>");

$.each(new_array, function(index, value){

    //Adding elements on each table created
  $("#print_receipt tbody").append(
    "<table><tr><td>"+
    value.catalog_name+
    "</td><td>"+
    value.price+
    "</td><td>"+
    value.qty+
    "</td><td>"+
    value.amt+
    "</td></tr></tbody></table>"
  );
});

for(var j=0;j < data.length; j++)
{
    $("#print_receipt").append(
        "</tbody><tfoot><tr><td colspan='3'>TOTAL</td><td>"+
    data[j].grand+
    "</td></tr><tr><td colspan='3'>CASH</td><td>"+
    data[j].cash+
    "</td></tr><tr><td colspan='3'>CHANGE</td><td>"+
    data[j].change+
    "</td></tr></tfoot></table><br/><table><tr><td>Customer Info<br/>Member Id: "+
    data[j].cust_id+
    "<br/>Name: "+
    data[j].cust_name+
    "<br/><input type='button' id='print_now' onClick = 'window.print()' value='PRINT RECEIPT'/></td></tr></table>");  
}
```

Other than that:
-Pay attention to your coding style, which is difficult to read. In the fiddle linked you'll see how I would write it to read it easier.

-Don't make tables for non-tabular information (arguably, the information before and after the tables is non-tabular (not inside a table at least))

-Make only one table, try not to make tables inside tables

Comment: thanks for the better coding ideas.. I tried your code, however i still get the middle table repeats twice. I've no why is it so.

Comment: Yeah, in the fiddle the problem is not corrected, I just highlighted the problem for you to solve it. Did you understand what the problem was?

Comment: I see how the table structure is organized in your coding but still can't understand why the middle table repeats

Comment: Oh, yeah, you are right, there is another error. You are creating a table, and then, after the table, a tbody. HTML creates a tbody once you create a table, so what happens is: 1- you create the table 2- inside the table, html creates a tbody 3- you open a tobody after the table. This results in having 2 tbody elements. So jquery finds both and inserts the same content in each. -> line 46 in the fiddle (where you are opening the tbody, just remove the tag).

Edit: I think this was the problem from the beginning and I understood otherwise. Let me know if this was it and I'll update the answer

Comment: exactly, I removed the tbody and appended to $("#print_receipt") , now it doesn't repeat

Answer (score 0):

@Keren for templating use templating engines like handlebars. or some other libraries.that will make your code more readable and can be easily debuggable.

avoid templating in jquery.handlebars templats will show anyone what you are trying to do.if you do templating by using jquery that will make your code less readable.

and also templating should not happen inside script.script's should be separate and templates should be separate.that will make your code testable